# Append contents of file to another file with different encoding

Tags: java, file, stream

I wanted to append contents of file to which `Path path` leads to.
To the file of path: `String resultFileName`.

The source is in `Cp1250` endoding the result is in `UTF-8` encoding. I managed to do it but unfortunately I add spare `\n` in the end of target file. I would like to get rid of that `\n`.

```
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(resultFileName), "utf-8"));
    Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.forName("Windows-1250")).stream().forEach((line) -> {
    try {
        bw.write(line);
        bw.newLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

I think that there must be a one liner which appends contents of one file to the another and changes encoding in the process.

Answer (score 1):

There is convenient library `apache-commons-io` where exists util class `IOUtils`.

Via this library you can do what you are looking for in single line:

```
IOUtils.copy(Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), bw);
```

Comment: I am forced to use built in solutions. No 3rd party libriaries.